# Why would Django respond with differently to the same request

Tags: python, django, api

We've recently inherited a Django project which is new territory for me. In debugging an issue I've come across something I've never seen before in my 20 years of programming.

I have an API (written in Django) which has multiple end points (usual user profile stuff). When I make a GET request I get a response in the format I expect, however each time I make the request the subset of data is different.

I have attached 3 screenshots of the Postman request immediately following new user sign up, these are taken seconds apart with no changes to the data. I can continually make the requests and cycle through the 3 states.

[image: Missing Nothing]

[image: Missing search criteria]

[image: Missing profile data and search criteria]

This is the code for the endpoint:

```
class UserProfile(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = SRUserSerializer
    queryset = SRUser.objects
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = request.user
        instance.not_now_count = instance.not_now.all().count()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The only thing I can assume is that the serializer is making additional data requests to the database but returning the data before they have necessarily returned. Would there be a way to identify this? What else can I provide to help identify the issue?

This is a Django 1.9 instance running on AWS using MySQL as a data store

Comment: You may want to edit your pictures so that token/url info isnt in them.

Comment: Could you be a little more clear as to what exactly the problem is? It looks like your JSON is in a slightly different order, but that's to be expected if it's being generated from a dict, which is inherently unordered. Is any of the data actually *different*?

Comment: I'm not worried about the token it's test data. The server key isn't displayed either way.

Comment: With regards the issue.....If you see the data itself is changing for example the search and profile lat long fields